# Google search console and app indexing: URI unsupported

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-app-indexing

I'm trying to implement app indexing on Android.

I've got an intent-filter, the following:

```
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="www.hotelsclick.com" />
            <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="www.hotelsclick.com" />
        </intent-filter>
```

and I can call the activity from adb with this command

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://www.hotelsclick.com?hotel_id=135738"
```

Thus, I cannot manage to make the "Fetch as google" feature work.

[image]

I was wondering: how can I understand what's not working in the "fetch as google" feature? "URI unsupported" is quite a useless trace. How can I debug this?

Thank you

Comment: Is your app (latest build with app-indexing implemented) uploaded to Google Play Store?

Comment: No, it's not, the uploaded APK doesn't feature app indexing. But I uploaded a app-indexing probe version and used that for "Fetch as google": isn't that enough? Thank you

Comment: It should be enough. But you must be doing something wrong. Because if you are using a local upload APK, you will see a tick mark in 4th column of above pic. http://imgur.com/p2WrPjE

Comment: You're right, I must have done something wrong. I chose the APK again and performed the search, now I don't get "URL unsupported" but "Internal error". Which is even more generic, alas. https://i.imgsafe.org/b95f5b8.png

Comment: Yes. I keep getting it often. I think you can ignore that and try with a different url.

Comment: I keep getting that error with other URLs as well... could it be because of the ?hotel_id=135738 format instead of /hotel_id/135738? Maybe app indexing does not like GET parameters...

Comment: I don't think its a problem with the GET parameters. I got "Internal Error" for few URL structures and the other URLs worked fine. I went ahead and published the app, I don't get that error now anymore for the published app. Since this discussion is going away from the main question, I suggest you to post a new question if you need anything else.

Comment: Makes sense. Anyway thank you, I'll try and upload a beta version with app indexing enabled.

Comment: Actually, I'd expect it to work at least with this tool: https://applinktest.appspot.com/app-link.html?url=android-app%3A%2F%2Fcom.towers.hotelsclick%2Fhttps%2Fhotelsclick.com%3Fhotel_id%3D135738 but it doesn't...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Fetch as Google" can fetch a page from either the current version on Google Play  or from an APK that you upload here.

If you are using a local upload, then you will see a "tick" mark in the "Local Upload APK" column after the fetch results are shown (check image below).

[image]

Since, it is not there in the image you provided, the fetch is happening from the Google Play version of your app. Check if it has app indexing implemented in this version.